# custom ul li in autocomplete jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an autocomplete with jquery:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="https://www.google.com/#q=" method="get">
        <input id="input_submit" class="input_search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search...">
        <input class="input_submit" type="submit" value="SEARCH">
        <span id="myAutocompleteMsg"></span>
 </form>
```

With js code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#searchForm').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var search = $('.input_search').val();
                var url = $(this).attr('action');
                // alert('search=' + search + ' url=' + url);
                console.log(x, "s");
                window.location.href = url + search;
            });

            $("#input_submit").autocomplete({
                source: ["yegane", "salami", "ali", "alpha"],
            });

            $("#input_submit").on("keyup", function() {
                //console.log("typing");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    if (($(".ui-autocomplete").css("display") == "none") && ($("#myAutocomplete").val() != "")) {
                        console.log("No result!");
                        $("#ui-id-1").html("Sorry!The url is not avaible");
                    } else {
                        $("#myAutocompleteMsg").html("");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I have tried the code above . but how can i render the results in custom ul li that if the results is in array shows in ul li but if the result is not in the array display "no result" in ul li to.

Comment: have you read the autocomplete documentation ?

Comment: i have read but how can i render "no data" in autocomplete when the input text is not in source? @madalinivascu

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/er6LF/